# Button hidden behind my BaseViewController in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uibutton

I am facing weird problem. I have a baseViewController which extends with UIViewController. 
in My BaseView controller i have a custom HeaderBar (UIImageView) on top of it.

I then made a new ViewController and extends that new ViewController with baseViewController. The headerBar in BaseViewController is appearing on my UIViewController. But now if I add any subview in my NEWViewController over that headerBar then it does not come over that whereas it goes behind the header bar.

Can anybody suggest what to do.

***EDITED***

Here is my code.

***BASEViewController***

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
CGFloat xOffset = 0;
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    xOffset = 224;
}

self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization

   headerBarView = [self addHeaderBar];
    //[self.view addSubview:headerBarView];
    [self.view insertSubview:headerBarView belowSubview:self.view];

}

return self;
}
-(UIView *)addHeaderBar{

UIView *header_bar = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320, 50.0)];

//HeaderBar Image
UIImageView *headerBar = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0.0, 320, 50.0)];
[headerBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top_bar"]];
[header_bar addSubview:headerBar];
return header_bar;
}
```

***NEWViewController Extended With BaseViewController***

```
  //Back Button
back =  [UI getActionBarButtonWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Back"] andCGRect:CGRectMake(7.0, 100.0, 55.0, 31.0) andEdgeInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 9.0, 2.0, 0.0) withBackGround:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_button"]]; 
   [self.view bringSubviewToFront:back];

+(UIButton *)getActionBarButtonWithName:(NSString *)name andCGRect:(CGRect)rect andEdgeInset:(UIEdgeInsets)edgeInset withBackGround:(UIImage *)background{

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = rect;
[button setBackgroundImage:background forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitleEdgeInsets:edgeInset];
[button setTitle:name forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13.0]];
[button setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

return button;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are having many views, you can also use any one of these -

```
[self.view insertSubview:<#(UIView *)#> aboveSubview:<#(UIView *)#>]
[self.view insertSubview:<#(UIView *)#> atIndex:<#(NSInteger)#>]
[self.view insertSubview:<#(UIView *)#> belowSubview:<#(UIView *)#>]
```

hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:button];
```

Answer (score 0):

New UIVIew override your base viewcontroller,you can set frame of new view and then add subview.

Ex. UIView* tempView=[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,44,320,420)];
[self.view addSubView:temView];

Comment: can you share .h file code and when you will add any other subview code